# Multiple fs.createReadStream in a try catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have multiple statements containing `fs.createReadStream()`. I know we can handle errors by listening to `on('error',cb)` event but the code will get messy if I started listening to `error` event on each stream. I want it to be clean this:

```
try{
    var file1 = fs.createReadStream(path1),
        file2 = fs.createReadStream(path2),
        file3 = fs.createReadSTream(path3),
        ....
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

But it doesn't work like this. Is there anyway I can use the above like code structure to handle error instead of listening to `error`event on each stream?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Why not wrap `fs.createReadStream()` with a function that takes a path and attaches an `error` handler? That should yield reasonably clean code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

Assuming you can consolidate the error handling logic (which you would be in a try-catch case anyway), then just create one function and use it as the `error` handler for each stream:

```
var file1 = fs.createReadStream(path1).on('error', onError),
    file2 = fs.createReadStream(path2).on('error', onError),
    file3 = fs.createReadSTream(path3).on('error', onError);

function onError(err) {
  // `this` === stream that encountered the error
  console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can not use `try/catch` to catch asynchronous `error` event. Read detail about [Node.js Errors](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html).

In this case, the `error` event of `fs.createReadStream` will happen after `try/catch` code execution.

Consider using synchronous methods, like `fs.readFileSync`, if you really want `try/catch`.

```
try{
    var file1 = fs.readFileSync(path1),
        file2 = fs.readFileSync(path2),
        file3 = fs.readFileSync(path3),
        ....
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```